# Loading ImageIcon from JAR

Tags: java, imageicon

I can not load the images for my card game. My card class extends ImageIcon and I specify the path of the card image in the super method. When I compile and run it in TextPad it works, but when I export it into a JAR file I get null pointer exception.

My code is like this:

```
super(Card.class.getResource("images/" + imagePath));
```

I have tried with:

```
super("images/" + imagePath);
super(Card.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/" + imagePath));
```

This is from the decompiler of the jar file:

[Decompiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY9U1.jpg)

Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure your jar file contains the images in the right place?
If you have class file `/your/package/Card.class` then your images should be `/your/package/images/something.png`.

Comment: This is from the decompiler of the jar file: http://i.imgur.com/6pMeLlN.jpg